# typecasting an int to byte and vice versa

Tags: casting, integer, byte

I have an integer (val) 355, I converted it into byte (b) using typecasting and got 99

```
int val = 355;
byte b = (byte) val; //b contains 99
```

Now I am not able to convert this 99 again into 355, what I tried is given below

```
int returnVal = (int) b; //returnVal contains 99
int converted = returnVal & 0xFF; //converted contains 99
```

How can I convert 99 into 355?

In 2nd scenario, values are different. Now,

```
int val = 161;
byte b = (byte) val; //b contains -95
int returnVal = (int) b; //returnVal contains -95
int converted = returnVal & 0xFF; //converted contains 161
```

In the 2nd scenario the value is converted successfully but not in first.

Answer (score 1):

You lose information when you go from int to byte. You get `x & 0xFF` for any input x.

And this process is irreversible. This is like taking a galon of milk, pouring it into a pint glass, then pouring the pint glass into an empty gallon and wondering why the gallon isn't full.

Comment: The only difference I see in the above scenarios is that in 2nd scenario the byte value is negative while in first one the value is positive. Is there any way to solve this misery?

Comment: Read about signed and unsigned representations of integers. Complement-of-2 and the like.

Comment: The basic problem is still there: A gallon doesn't fit in a pint.

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario, 355 is 0x01, 0x63. One Byte only has 8 bits, so 0x01 should be ignored when typecasting, 0x63 is 99, so you got 99, but never revert to 0x01, 0x63, which is 355.

Comment: What is the solution? How will I get 355?